# Error installing boost 1.74.0 using conan on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: c++, boost, conan

I am trying to install boost but i get this error

> ERROR: boost/1.74.0: Cannot load recipe. Error loading conanfile at
> '/home/pi/.conan/data/boost/1.74.0/*/*/export/conanfile.py': Unable to
> load conanfile in
> /home/pi/.conan/data/boost/1.74.0/*/*/export/conanfile.py   File
> "/home/pi/.conan/data/boost/1.74.0/*/*/export/conanfile.py", line 510
> tools.get(**self.conan_data["sources"][self.version],destination=self._source_subfolder,
> strip_root=True)
> ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

**This my conanfile.py**

```
from conans import ConanFile, CMake

class ConanPackage(ConanFile):
    name = 'network-monitor'
    version = "0.1.0"

    generators = 'cmake_find_package'

    requires = [
        ('boost/1.74.0')
    ]

    default_options = (
        'boost:shared=False'
    )
```

**And this is the full output after running this command**

```
conan install .. --profile ../conanprofile.toml
```

> Configuration: [settings] arch=armv7 arch_build=armv7
> build_type=Release compiler=gcc compiler.libcxx=libstdc++11
> compiler.version=8 os=Linux os_build=Linux [options] [build_requires]
> [env]
>
> ERROR: boost/1.74.0: Cannot load recipe. Error loading conanfile at
> '/home/pi/.conan/data/boost/1.74.0/*/*/export/conanfile.py': Unable to
> load conanfile in
> /home/pi/.conan/data/boost/1.74.0/*/*/export/conanfile.py   File
> "/home/pi/.conan/data/boost/1.74.0/*/*/export/conanfile.py", line 510
> tools.get(**self.conan_data["sources"][self.version],
> ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Which Conan and Python version are you running? It seems be related to incompatible version. The strip_root requires Conan 1.30 or newer. Also, Conan still supports Python 2.7 but it strongly recommends Python 3+

Comment: Conan version 1.36.0
Python 3.7.3

Comment: I can't reproduce your case for x64. It should be a package limitation due your platform. I suggest you opening an issue to https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index/issues, explaining your case, with more details (issue's template list those details). Only x64 is validated by default, but extra platform support is always welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The default python version was 2.7, i have set the default python version to 3.7 and reinstalled all the tools and conan installed it properly.

this is a tutorial on how to set python default version on raspberry pi
https://raspberry-valley.azurewebsites.net/Python-Default-Version/